# Oracle Trace File Interpretation: enq: TX - index contention

Tags: oracle

### Background

I've got an application which is doing a large number of concurrent inserts into an Oracle table. The Top Activity view is reporting a lot of index contention and I am attempting to reduce this to improve performance.

The table in question has several indexes, but my suspicion is that the problem is leaf-block contention on the PK which is a monotonically increasing sequence. I know about reverse key indexes, but I'd like to be able to pin-point the problem before I dive in with guesswork fixes.

### Trace File Contents

I've extracted a trace from the database when under load. I've included a chunk of it at the bottom, but one part in particular is puzzling me. The largest "enq: TX - index contention" entry accounts for 94% of the total time:

```
WAIT #47156432773600: nam='enq: TX - index contention' ela= 113183 name|mode=1415053316 usn<<16 | slot=4259845 sequence=43226 obj#=-1 tim=1329387810694927
```

I don't understand how to interpret this line. Googling has yielded that `name|mode=1415053316` means Transaction in share mode (hex TX04), and that `obj#` would reference the object in SYS.OBJ$.

For the other waits where `obj#` *is* specified (see below), it points to the PK index I have suspicions about, but in the largest wait, the `obj#=-1`.

So, my questions are:

- What does it mean for `obj#` to be -1 in this wait?
- What does the `usn<<16 | slot=4259845` parameter mean? Is it useful to me?
- Does the `sequence=43226` tell me anything useful?

### More trace detail

```
PARSING IN CURSOR #47156432773600 len=654 dep=0 uid=41 oct=2 lid=41 tim=1329387810581386 hv=3365236844 ad='2977ccca8' sqlid='31r3hm349aw3c'
insert into AnonymousTable (a, b, c ...) values (:1, :2, :3 ...)
END OF STMT
PARSE #47156432773600:c=0,e=51,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=0,og=1,plh=0,tim=1329387810581384
WAIT #47156432773600: nam='enq: TX - index contention' ela= 113183 name|mode=1415053316 usn<<16 | slot=4259845 sequence=43226 obj#=-1 tim=1329387810694927
WAIT #47156432773600: nam='latch: ges resource hash list' ela= 3958 address=11249153232 number=91 tries=0 obj#=-1 tim=1329387810698944
WAIT #47156432773600: nam='enq: TX - index contention' ela= 1891 name|mode=1415053316 usn<<16 | slot=655387 sequence=48341 obj#=-1 tim=1329387810700949
WAIT #47156432773600: nam='buffer busy waits' ela= 162 file#=32 block#=618823 class#=1 obj#=28134 tim=1329387810701223
WAIT #47156432773600: nam='buffer busy waits' ela= 1572 file#=32 block#=618823 class#=1 obj#=28134 tim=1329387810702840
WAIT #47156432773600: nam='enq: TX - index contention' ela= 1809 name|mode=1415053316 usn<<16 | slot=5767194 sequence=85968 obj#=28134 tim=1329387810704709
WAIT #47156432773600: nam='buffer busy waits' ela= 2254 file#=32 block#=618823 class#=1 obj#=28134 tim=1329387810707018
WAIT #47156432773600: nam='enq: TX - index contention' ela= 15306 name|mode=1415053316 usn<<16 | slot=4784132 sequence=53965 obj#=28134 tim=1329387810722436
EXEC #47156432773600:c=1999,e=142776,p=0,cr=50,cu=364,mis=0,r=28,dep=0,og=1,plh=0,tim=1329387810724203
STAT #47156432773600 id=1 cnt=0 pid=0 pos=1 obj=0 op='LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL  (cr=50 pr=0 pw=0 time=142726 us)'
WAIT #47156432773600: nam='SQL*Net message to client' ela= 2 driver id=1413697536 #bytes=1 p3=0 obj#=28134 tim=1329387810724288
WAIT #47156432773600: nam='SQL*Net message from client' ela= 363 driver id=1413697536 #bytes=1 p3=0 obj#=28134 tim=1329387810724667
CLOSE #47156432773600:c=0,e=7,dep=0,type=1,tim=1329387810724701
```

Comment: What are the `INITRANS` and `MAXTRANS` settings for the table and indexes in question?  It's possible that the blocks in question lack an appropriate number of ITL slots.

Comment: The `INITRANS` is small. I agree that it's likely that there's contention for ITL slots. What I'd really like though is concrete evidence that this index is the problem before I go changing stuff.

Comment: I also think that swapping to a reverse-key index or a non-increasing sequence might be a better solution that just increasing `INITRANS`. Do you agree?

I really need this to work in a RAC environment too.

Comment: The lowest impact solution would be to increase `INITRANS` to an appropriate level.  Another solution would be to hash-partition the index; suddenly one really hot leaf block is now 8 or 16 leaf blocks under 1/8th or 1/16 of the pressure.  If using RAC and the load on this is going to be coming from multiple nodes, you need to partition both the table and the load along another dimension; tossing the leaf blocks across the interconnect is not going to work at all.

Comment: Roughly how many inserts per second are you pushing into the table? Have you any option to use array inserts with less concurrent sessions to complete your workload?  I *think* the TX Contention wait doesn't point you at the block / object that is causing the problems, but my memory is a bit fuzzy in that area.

Comment: In this particular case I'm getting insert rates of around 4k per second, which isn't bad.

What I'd really like is to improve my tuning method in general, rather than optimise this specific case. In all most other profiling aspects (this is one part of a large Java app) I can pin-point the bottleneck before tackling it, but here the only approach seems to be educated guesswork.

Why do some of the TX contention lines have an obj# while others don't? Is it just an un-cleared variable? Does that mean that none of them are reliable?

Comment: @TimGage are u still seeking for an answer? I can give you an hand

Comment: Yes - I would definitely still like to have an answer.

Comment: @TimGage could you also report version and platform?

Comment: This was 11gR2 on RHEL 5.6, as I recall. The precise setup was a performance testing environment and has since been updated.

Answer (score 2):

OBJ#=-1 means either means that the object number is missing or it's not related to an object.
The best idea is to go into V$active_session_history and find the SQL_ID then get the SQL text via the SQL_ID and look at the object sin the SQL and what the SQL was doing.

As far as people suggesting INIT TRANS, that is unlikely as there is a separate wait event for INIT TRANS.

USN, SLOT and SEQUENCE  map the UNDO entry for the transaction.
They could be used to map back to activity in the UNDO but it's probably easier to get the transaction id the XID and use VERSIONS_XID on the objects involved.

see http://www.slideshare.net/khailey/ukoug-oracle-transaction-locks

Example ASH query

```
col object for A15
col otype for A10
select
      substr(event,0,20)    lock_name,
      ash.session_id        waiter,
      mod(ash.p1,16)        lmode,
      --ash.p2                p2,
      --ash.p3                p3,
      o.object_name           object,
      o.object_type           otype,
      CURRENT_FILE#           filen,
      CURRENT_BLOCK#          blockn,
      ash.SQL_ID             waiting_sql,
      BLOCKING_SESSION        blocker
      --,ash.xid
from
        v$active_session_history ash,
        all_objects o
where
          event like 'enq: TX - index contention'
  and o.object_id (+)= ash.CURRENT_OBJ#
/
```

Answer (score 0):

OBJ#=-1 means that the event is not relateable to any particular object.

These values are almost certainly the P1 P2 and P3 values dumped from the wait event. You should query v$event_name if you want to know what these values mean, although this will almost certainly send you tumbling further down the rabbit hole that is Oracle performance.

Comment: Agreed, but `v$event_name` just tells me the same thing as is reported in the trace: `name|mode`, `usn<<16|slot`, `sequence`

In the end I gave up went of the old fashioned method of making assumptions and testing them. It worked, but it's a shame that there isn't more detail available to diagnose these problems non-intrusively.

Comment: It's one of the ways that Oracle allows you to look "under the hood" as it were, but it's a mixed blessing.